# How to move this bootstrap 4 form vertically center of the screen?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

We are trying to move the sign in form with the card to the center of the screen vertically but the issue is that it stays on the top of the screen.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12  close-form">
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-circle button-image closeButton float-right"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-row ">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto signinform">
            <div class="card card-signin my-5">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Sign In</h5>
                    <div>
                        <div id="errorMsg" *ngIf="errorMessage">
                            <span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <form action="" [formGroup]="SigninForm" (ngSubmit)="signinUser()">
                            <div class="form-group form-signin">
                                <input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Username"
                                    type="text" id="username" formControlName="username" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-signin">
                                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password"
                                    formControlName="password" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-signin">
                                <div class="extra-btns align-items-center">
                                    <a href="/request-reset-password" class="btn btn-link ">Forget password</a>
                                    <a href="/sign-up" class="btn btn-link ">Sign Up</a>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="  btn form-btn btn-lg btn-block submit-btn">
                                        Sign In
                                        With Email
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
:root {
  --input-padding-x: 1.5rem;
  --input-padding-y: .75rem;
}

.container-fluid {
    height: 150%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FF512F; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(221, 36, 118, 0.7), rgba(255, 81, 47, 0.2)), url('../../../assets/images/img1.jpg'); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(221, 36, 118, 0.7), rgba(255, 81, 47, 0.2)), url('../../../assets/images/img1.jpg'); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    margin: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100vh;
}
    .container-fluid.form.signup {
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        height: 100%;
    }
.card.card-signin.my-5,
.card.card-signup.my-5 {
 /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-sm-9.col-md-7.col-lg-5.mx-auto {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top:0px
}
```

We are using Bootstrap 4 with Angular. How can this issue be fixed? How can we move sign in form with its card move to the center of the screen vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the height of `.row` or `.row-form` that contains the signin card is set by default to match the size of its children's content.

Give `.form-row` a height value of 100% `.form-row {height:100%}`. Just one single class. I hope this helps. Try the snippet out.

```css
:root {
  --input-padding-x: 1.5rem;
  --input-padding-y: .75rem;
}

.container-fluid {
    height: 150%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FF512F; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(221, 36, 118, 0.7), rgba(255, 81, 47, 0.2)), url('../../../assets/images/img1.jpg'); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(221, 36, 118, 0.7), rgba(255, 81, 47, 0.2)), url('../../../assets/images/img1.jpg'); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    margin: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100vh;
}
    .container-fluid.form.signup {
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        height: 100%;
    }
.card.card-signin.my-5,
.card.card-signup.my-5 {
 /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-sm-9.col-md-7.col-lg-5.mx-auto {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top:0px
}

.form-row {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12  close-form">
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-circle button-image closeButton float-right"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-row ">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto signinform">
            <div class="card card-signin my-5">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Sign In</h5>
                    <div>
                        <div id="errorMsg" *ngIf="errorMessage">
                            <span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <form action="" [formGroup]="SigninForm" (ngSubmit)="signinUser()">
                            <div class="form-group form-signin">
                                <input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Username"
                                    type="text" id="username" formControlName="username" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-signin">
                                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password"
                                    formControlName="password" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-signin">
                                <div class="extra-btns align-items-center">
                                    <a href="/request-reset-password" class="btn btn-link ">Forget password</a>
                                    <a href="/sign-up" class="btn btn-link ">Sign Up</a>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="  btn form-btn btn-lg btn-block submit-btn">
                                        Sign In
                                        With Email
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `flex`:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}

.close-button-container {
  text-align: right;
  padding: .5rem;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.form-container {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form-card {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="close-button-container">
        x Close
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
        <div class="form-card">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button>
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**This is what the code does:**

Sets `height: 100%` on both your `html` and `body` tags. This will allow you to stretch `div.content`, vertically filling the whole page.

Afterwards, we want the close button to have a fixed height, and let `div.form-container` take what's left of the page.

According to [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

> [flex-grow] defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It dictates what amount of the available space inside the flex container the item should take up.
>
> If all items have flex-grow set to 1, the remaining space in the container will be distributed equally to all children. If one of the children has a value of 2, the remaining space would take up twice as much space as the others (or it will try to, at least).

So, setting `flex: 1` (a shorthand for `flex-grow: 1`) on only a single tag will tell the browser to stretch this single tag and fill the remaining space of the container.

Now, all that is left is to tell `div.form-container` to place `div.form-card` in its center; both vertically and horizontally. This is achieved with `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`.